# Voltage Controlled-Phase Shifting Circuits

Tags: frequency-modulation, phase-shift

Forewarned: I have a somewhat good understanding of signals and systems but electrical engineering circuits aren't my strength.

Question: Is there a simple circuit that can introduce a voltage-controlled phase shift on a FM signal (especially for frequencies in the 10's of kHz)?

Complication: There are tons of results that pop up after Googling for voltage-controlled phase shifting (VCPS ) circuits but I can't be sure which are frequency independent and all the other potential limitations that might not satisfy the intent of my question.

[This IC](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Skyworks%20PDFs/PS214-315.pdf) would seem to be suitable but I'm not completely sure.

Here's another [simpler example](http://www.eleccircuit.com/single-transistor-phase-shifter/) I found closer to the frequency range I am interested in.

Comment: Check figure 6. Phase more or less linear with frequency. What exactly **is** your question?

Comment: If I have a phase shifting circuit and I put in a signal from (say) a chirped sinewave, will the output of the circuit be that chirped sinewave phase shifted by the amount of shift specified by the voltage control?

From what I have seen some of the circuits that pop up on google are for a specific frequency or have other limitations.

Comment: For instance google search "frequency independent phase shifter" - the frequency independent nature seems to imply that some circuits are frequency dependent.

Comment: Could you explain why you want a voltage controlled phase shift circuit because there may be a better approach. All the phase shift circuits I know either are not frequency independant or alter amplitude across the range of frequencies. Are you in fact looking to get a fixed 90 deg phase shift rahter than be able to vary it?

Comment: Where is the signal coming from? Is the hardware that generates it already in existence, or is it being designed now? One solution to this problem, depending on what you are doing, would be to generate two signals at the same time using two DDS's. Then you would have a perfect phase difference between your two signals over the full chirp bandwidth. You could also vary the phase difference at will (in some DDs's). I think you really need to explain more about what you are doing.

Comment: I am not looking to get a fixed phase shift, I want to be able to control the phase at "run-time" via a voltage "command."  The impetus for my question was directly tied to what I found in a google search related to your comment: "All the phase shift circuits I know either are not frequency independant or alter amplitude across the range of frequencies."

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to disclose the details of the invention other than what I have already done.  I know this makes it harder for you and I apologize.

I don't care about the specific circuit design; I just want to know if there is a circuit that can achieve it.  I am definitely open to other options especially if they are lower cost.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: The hardware is not yet specified; it is blank slate.

Comment: So far as the source of the signal is concerned, picture someone standing and holding a knob that adjusts frequency at runtime; they can adjust the frequency however they like during the course of producing the signal.  The output of the circuit should produce the same signal phased shifted by whatever the voltage controlled phase shift command is.

Comment: The amplitude of the signal would be constant.

Comment: This sounds like a good application for a dual DDS solution. The DDS's would be clocked by the same syncrhonous clock. Software on some kind of microprocessor would watch the frequency knob turned by the user and also watch the voltage command signal, and then update the registers in the two DDS's to produce the two desired outputs with perfectly synchronous frequency and phase shift controlled by voltage.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds useful but the point of the circuit is to get rid of the micro controller and used completely analogue circuits.  I should have established that from the outset. :)

Comment: No way that I know of but I am definitely not an expert. Maybe hire a PLL or RF expert or something for a short consult.

Comment: Can you suggest someone or somewhere to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR the part you've linked to is suitable for whatever you want, if you're working in the 1.7 to 2.7GHz region.

Figure 6 of the data sheet shows this

[image]

For the higher voltages, at constant control voltage, the phase shift with frequency is flat (to my eye) over a 1GHz bandwidth, so is acting like a length of cable. For the lower voltages, I can see a few degrees of bend over that bandwidth, so it's a bit more dispersive than cable. Microstrip is weakly dispersive, though I don't know whether more or less than these low voltage curves. An FM signal covering a 1GHz bandwidth at only 2ish GHz would be quite some signal! For any lesser bandwidth, 100MHz or so, you could call this as flat as cable at all voltages.

For the higher voltages, the phase shift with voltage is slightly greater at high frequencies. For the lower voltages, the phase shift with voltage is less at high frequencies. Between 7v and 8v (by my eye) it appears that the change of phase with voltage is essentially independent of frequency over the 1GHz bandwidth. Again, over a more reasonable bandwidth like 100MHz, it's effectively flat at all control voltages.

Comment: A lot of work has been done in this domain but I think I've found a solution from this patent:
https://www.google.com/patents/US3319188

See figure 2