# Phase-Shifting Commutation

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, phase-shift

I posted a question a while ago about a circuit to realize a voltage controlled phase.  I wasn't able to give a full discussion about why I was interested in the circuit at the time but I am in a position to do so now.

I have filed a provisional patent for "phase shifting commutation" with this abstract:

> The apparatus employs magnetoresistive sensors (28) to generate a sinusoid having a time-varying frequency commensurate with the angular rate of change of a motor’s rotating shaft (40).  The resultant signal is then fed to a mixture of fixed- and voltage-controlled phase shifting circuits (22, 64) (32) whose outputs are then amplified and fed to independently wired stator phases (56).  The apparatus also includes a rotary transformer (24, 36, 46, 60) whose current is generated by amplifying a frequency-shifted version of this shaft sinusoid.  The rotary transformer (24, 36, 46, 60) in turn supplies current to the rotor system’s electromagnet to generate a controllable magnetic on the rotor system despite the rotor system’s motion.
>   [image: Phase-shifting commutation][image: element list]

My former employer is investigating this methodology and has the right to use the technology but I am in control of the IP.  I am building a mini dynamometer chassis with BLDC motors and I want to build the circuitry to achieve this commutation technique so that I have something to demonstrate.

A voltage controlled phase shifting circuit seems entirely achievable as there are many available off the shelf that operate with center frequencies in the GHz range.  Also consider that this technology is key to phased-array systems.

So I am wondering if anyone can help me build this phase-shifting circuit or can recommend some solution that I don't know about.

---

- [Off-the-shelf phase shifting circuit](http://www.lorch.com/pdf/vcps.pdf)
- [Detailed discussion of phase shifting circuits](http://web.stanford.edu/~adapoon/papers/pieee12_array.pdf)
- [Previous thread of discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261057/voltage-controlled-phase-shifting-circuits)

---

Comment: Please add additional information to your question by editing it, rather than as comments or answers.

Comment: I am not following everything. But wouldn't it be much easier to do this using a microprocessor and a shaft position encoder? You could generate basically any signal you can dream up from that.

Comment: I suspect that your request for a consultant is off-topic and will get your question closed. Check the [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I have corrected the post

Comment: Elsewhere you mention that a motivation for your approach is to support higher speeds than are possible with a micro-controller. Can you specifiy what frquency you need to support? This would be max RPM * 60 * N where N is the number of magnetic pole pairs (two magnets = pair).

Comment: Im not sure i would empose a top speed on the motor; it seems unnecessary given the approach

Comment: @JordanMcBain, are you aware of applications where motors need to be driven faster than, say, 1kHz or 10kHz? What is the fastest motor drive application you are aware of (fastest in terms of electrical frequency). I am trying to understand if there is actually any practical application for your system. I have heard of 10,000 RPM motors, and very small 100,000 RPM motors. That is the fastest I have ever heard of. But 100,000 RPM is only in the 10's of kHz (depending on pole count). At that speed, I would think some type of digital solution would just be much easier.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: electrical frequency = RPM/60*N

Comment: Im not sure that motor speed is necessarily the main objecti e.  Id say the invention gets rid of the complications of SVPWM techniques and the emi and inefficiencies that result from not having a very clean sinusoidal current.

Comment: PWM produces a very nice sinusoid current. The emi comes from dV/dt. But you are not proposing to run a motor from a linear amplifier are you? Anyway, this is my last comment. I am just having trouble understanding where this would be used.

Comment: No class d amplifier.

Comment: If a microcontroller's control of a motor produces a nice sinusoid then electromagnetic compatibility would be a none issue in automotive... which isnt the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84216/discussion-between-mkeith-and-jordan-mcbain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the analog domain, i think like a voltage controlled phase shift would necessitate a voltage controlled impedance of some kind.  There are all kinds of funky ways this could be done for reactive components like with varactors (diodes whose reverse transfer capacitance has a high voltage dependence), saturable inductors (a varying DC voltage across the windings will induce a current which lowers the small signal inductance), etc.  Voltage controlled resistances are realized often for things like automatic gain control circuits for fixed output amplitude from variable input amplitudes, or sine oscillator stabilization.  These could be furnished with JFETs or optocouplers or blasting voltage controlled heat at RTD's or all kinds of other funky ways.  Now whether you need orthogonal control of phase and amplitude or not and how precise your open loop phase shift vs voltage characteristics need to be would dictate the direction of the design in addition to other practical matters like power, size, ranges, etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not that knowledgeable about motors but it is not even slightly clear to me how this phase shifting circuit relates to the commutation of the BLDC motor.  How would you describe the ultimate goal of this circuit from input to output on a higher level?

Comment: The optimal means of achieving BLDC is via sinusoid commutation.  I believe this is ordinarily achieved by a microprocessor outputing a frequency varying sinusoid with an ADC circuit.  Apparently this approach breaks down with motors operating at high speeds.  

The provisional patent basically has a magnetoresistive sensor output this sinusoid.  Each phase shifting device then tailors this signal for each of the stator's phases.  The first offers a 90 degree phase shift.  The second and third provide additional 120 degree shifts.

Comment: Of course, these phase-shifted signals then need to be amplified for each phase.